# How to exclude "AnyCPU" build from NuGet pack?

Tags: nuget

I ant to package a DLL which is only available for x86 and x64 Windows since it PInvokes into a native DLL.

I have this `nuspec` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>First Nuget release</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
    <tags>native ugly stuff</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="bin\Release" exclude="*.dll" />
    <file src="bin\x86\Release\**" target="runtimes/win-x86/lib/net461" />
    <file src="bin\x64\Release\**" target="runtimes/win-x64/lib/net461" />
  </files>
</package>
```

However, upon running `nuget pack -Properties Configuration=Release -NoDefaultExcludes`, the `AnyCPU` variant still resides in the generated package.

If I remove the `AnyCPU` build target altogether, I get this error:

```
Error NU5012: Unable to find 'C:\Users\RabJen\Documents\git\MySolution\MyNativeDLL\bin\Release\MynativeDLL.dll'. Make sure the project has been built.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If your package contains only the x86 and x64 dlls, and nothing else else content or contentFiles, you could try replacing all the `$variables$` with the real values, then `nuget pack file.nuspec`. If you don't pack the project, it won't try to pack the project output.

Comment: If I just do `nuget pack` with the nuspec file above, it tries to pack the `Debug` version.

Comment: `nuget pack` will look for the csproj and pack that, which includes getting the project output. `nuget pack whatever.nuspec` might not.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick.  I replaced everything with `$` with the real values and ran `nuget pack MyNativeDLL.nuspec`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't pass a file name to `nuget pack`, it will look for any MSBuild project files (like a `csproj`), build it, and include the output assemblies. I don't see any [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/tools/cli-ref-pack) to not include the project output.

Therefore, your best option would be to explicitly tell `nuget pack` the nuspec file, for example `nuget pack whatever.nuspec`. It means your build script will need to build the project before packing, as NuGet will no longer build your project, and you will also need to replace all the variables (anything surrounded by `$`'s) with actual values.